# uglify-maven-plugin adding exclude file list

Tags: maven, uglifyjs

I am trying to implement uglifyjs-maven-plugin. 
While using the configuration mentioned [here](https://github.com/tqh/uglifyjs-maven-plugin), I am getting error like `sourceDirectory is undefined or invalid`.

Using the configuration like

```
      <configuration>
         <sourceDirectory>target/snapshot/javascript</sourceDirectory>
         <outputDirectory>target/snapshot/javascript</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
```

its working fine. But how will I add exclude file list in the above configuration.
I have a js file of 900kb, when i am including that js file inside source directory, i am getting exception during maven build as " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError". Can anyone help me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that while the documentation (and probably the current implementation) supports file exclusions, the version available in the repository (1.0) is older and supports only `sourceDirectory`.

I have not found any newer version published anywhere, so I guess the best thing we can do is compile the latest version of the plugin manually and see if it supports what the documentation says.